# What precedence are types derived when using auto?

Tags: c++, type-conversion, auto

I'd like to know in what order are types derived when using auto in C++? For example if I have

> auto x = 12.5;

Will that result in a float or a double? Is there any reason it chooses one over the other in terms of speed,efficiency or size? And in what order are the types derived? Does it try int then double then string or is it not that simple?

Thanks

Comment: The type of the literal `12.5` is `double`, so `x` is a `double`.

Comment: All literals are unambiguous. `12.5` is a `double`, `12.5f` is a `float`.

Comment: auto picks the same type that template type deduction does for just `T`.

Comment: does your question refer only to literals?

Comment: @PiotrS. No not just literals. I'd like to know how it does it across the board. Is it similiar to template functions?

Comment: @PiPatrol except for braced-init-lists yes, the same rules are applied as for template argument deduction

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While C++ allows initialization of different typed variables with the same kind of literal, all literals in C++ have *one* specific type. Therefore the type deduction for `auto` variables does not need to be special for initialization with literals, it just takes the type of the right hand side (the single, unambiguous type of the literal, in your case) and applies it to the variable.
Examples for literals and their different types:

```
12.5   //double
12.5f  //float
13     //int
13u    //unsigned int
13l    //long
13ull  //unsigned long long
"foo"  //char const [4]
'f'    //char
```

So what about `float f = 12.5;`? Very simple: here the `float f` is initialized with a literal of type `double` and an implicit conversion takes place. `12.5` for itself *never* is `float`, it always is `double`.

An exception where the type of the `auto` variable does *not* have the type of the literal is when array-to-pointer decay takes place, which is the case for all string literals:

```
auto c = "bar"; //c has type char const*, while "bar" has type char const[4]
```

But this again is not special for literals but holds for all kinds of arrays:

```
int iarr[5] = {};
auto x = iarr; //x has type int*
```

Comment: `"foo"  //char const []`, the deduced type for `auto` is `const char*`, as it gets decayed

Comment: @PiotrS. I'll add a note that `auto` decays arrays to pointers, but the type of the literal itself is array.

Comment: To be precise, the type of the literal is `char const [4]`. `char const []` is a different type.

Comment: @T.C. thansk for the correction, I edited my answer.